# npm install in Jenkins OpenShift instant app

Tags: jenkins, openshift, npm-install

I have deployed the instant app `Jenkins` in my OpenShift account. I have created a new job and it's pulling the code from Bitbucket. It is a NodeJS project so I have added an action to execute:

```
npm install
```

but I get permission errors:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/56cef0c72d5271b01a000010/.npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/56cef0c72d5271b01a000010/.npm']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/lib/openshift/56cef0c72d5271b01a000010/.npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/56cef0c72d5271b01a000010/app-root/data/workspace/oauth2-server
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37
npm ERR! path /var/lib/openshift/56cef0c72d5271b01a000010/.npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/56cef0c72d5271b01a000010/.npm'
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! 3 errno
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/openshift/56cef0c72d5271b01a000010/app-root/data/workspace/oauth2-server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code undefined
npm ERR! not ok code 3
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Obviously, I have no permission to use `sudo npm install` in OpenShift. I have read about this problem but I can't solve it.

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Install the [NodeJS Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin%20).
2. Configure the plugin to install NodeJS from nodejs.org, and [pick your desired version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIQz7.png)
3. Configure your build job, and select **Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH** under Build Environment.